# Load Entity Framework object with child collection and selected child property values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm struggling to load an Entity Framework object with a navigation property and selected values of a child object.

A small model might look like this.

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    // Many, many other values that I don't need
}

public class Topic
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to load a `Book` with the `Topics` populated and also need `Author.Name` but not all of the other `Author` property values.

I tried

```
var allData = context.Books.Select(b => new { Book = b, b.Tags, b.Author.Name }).First();
allData.Book.Topics = book.Topics;
allData.Book.Topics.Add(context.Topics.First());
context.SaveChanges();
```

That doesn't really work since accessing `allData.Book.Topics` will load the values from the database again.

Another attempt was

```
context.Entry(allData.Book).Collection(b => b.Topics).CurrentValue = allData.Topics;
context.Entry(allData.Book).Collection(b => b.Topics).IsLoaded = true;
```

But that will treat the elements set for `Topics` as new elements and save duplicates in the database.

Comment: If you want to fetch an object graph into the context you can use Include : `var allData = context.Books.Include(b => b.Topics).Include(b => b.Author).ToList();` Your code projectw a single book to an anonymous type. Not sure if that was what you intended.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid since it would load the `Author` with all of its properties.